# Why I am getting 'Forbidden' when I try to login on my live codeigniter site?

Tags: apache, codeigniter-2

```
#Deny from all
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|upload|uploads|html|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This is my current .htaccess file and site is inside a sub-domain directory called clients. You can access the site here: http://clients.creditblitz.ca/

Comment: What URL gives you the forbidden error? Have you tried this tool? http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/

Comment: My site is on http://clients.creditblitz.ca/ and you can use any email and password and you will get the error. The link is however http://clients.creditblitz.ca/authenticate.

Comment: That tool won't show anything to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your given url is redirect to 404 page

http://clients.creditblitz.ca/authenticate

But access below url redirect to 200 response

http://clients.creditblitz.ca/index.php/authenticate

So, Please remove the index.php in codeIgniter Framework config file

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And apply below htaccess coding

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```