# Uploading CodeIgniter project to another domain, login/URL redirection not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I've inherited a CodeIgniter project from another developer. The code is currently uploaded to the customer's domain, and has all basic functionality in tact. I copied down the source files as-is from their FTP and uploaded it to my own domain as an effective QA environment, where I could test changes and have them reviewed before deploying to production (their current domain).

The login procedure works fine on their domain. However, when I attempt to log in to the site when hosted on my domain, it does not redirect the user after the log in procedure. No errors are shown, it loads a blank page (www.mydomain.com/login) and stops there.

My config/routes.php file accounts for '/login' here:

```
$route['login'] = 'auth/login';
```

Snippet from my auth contoller where it redirects the user post-login:

```
if($user->category == "admin"){
        redirect('admin/overview');
    } elseif($user->category == "client"){
        if($this->session->userdata("default_overview"))
        {
            $page = $this->session->userdata("default_overview");
            redirect(base_url("closings/".$page));
        }
        else
        {
            redirect(base_url('closings/today'));
        }
    }
```

.htaccess at root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(api|API)/[v,V]([0-9|\.]{1,5})/(.*)$ api/v$2/index.php?request=$3 [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(svg|ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

On their domain, this all works as expected. I'm unsure why the same code behaves differently on my end, and I'm not sure where best to begin looking. I'm using Dreamhost with PHP 5.6 (I'm unsure of their version of PHP, but can inquire if it could be a compatibility issue).

I know this may not be a lot to go off from, but as this is my first PHP/CodeIgniter project, I'm hoping there are several things that I could check that someone more experienced can think of off the top of their head. I'll gladly provide any additional information that is needed.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: if you have changed `$config['base_url']` in config/config.php then you can try different .htaccess files. [https://github.com/synanhero/codeigniter-3.0-.htaccess-file](https://github.com/synanhero/codeigniter-3.0-.htaccess-file)

Comment: @synan54 - I updated the base_url earlier this evening. I was sure that was going to fix it, but sadly it didn't change anything, so something is wrong beyond that. I'll look into tinkering with the htaccess file. Thanks for the help.

Comment: try to run short codes like `<?="short codes works";?>` if short code did not run search inside of script if it has short codes like this. also check index.php in root /   if it is development or not. change it to development. and try to see  errors `define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');` good luck            @09cody

Comment: I think you don't remove the index in your config file and htaccess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558176/why-i-am-getting-forbidden-when-i-try-to-login-on-my-live-codeigniter-site/34586442#34586442